# Yammer Embed won't complete load: JavaScript error in IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, embed, yammer

I've created as simple an OpenGraph embed for Yammer as the documentation allows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        yam.connect.embedFeed({
            container: "#yammerfeed",
            feedType: "open-graph"
        });

    </script>
```

In Internet Explorer 8.0 (Standards - no compatibility mode) and in Internet Explorer 9 (again, in IE9 Standards Document Mode), once I'm asked to log in (assuming I'm not already), The iframe shows the message "Please wait...", and then "Loading...", at which point it freezes.

In IE9 I get the following console errors using Developer Tools:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'Math' is undefined
latest_jquery-d4465d7c4037a25f51802ce13ef899d1.js, line 14 character 12808

SCRIPT5009: 'String' is undefined
js_sdk_login_proxy, line 10 character 7
```

The open graph embed does load successfully in IE10, IE11, Chrome and Safari.

Adding various other config (such as the network name, use_sso etc.) has no effect.

Changing the platform_embed.js location to: https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js makes no difference either.

Is there an issue with the JavaScript in the Yammer Embed?

Comment: To report Yammer bugs please use developer.yammer.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

We've seen similar behavior in our environment. All pop-up related stuff (logging in, accepting our app) failed because the pop-up fails to close in IE 8 while it works perfectly in Chrome.

In our case, we were able to fix this by adding adding *.yammer.com (over HTTPS) to our Trusted Sites in IE, as described here:
https://developer.yammer.com/upgrading-to-the-new-yammer-js-sdk/

Make sure your Trusted Sites don't run in Protected Mode, as this seems to be the cause of the problem.